# ADFS PowerShell Claims Rule Combination Sytax

Tags: powershell, claims-based-identity, adfs

After some success with simple rules, having trouble in ADFS Claim Rules PowerShell SnapIn with:

1. How to delete rules. EDIT: => poor man's way appears to be just define a new empty rule set.
2. How to append rules without setting them all in one command.
3. Syntax for logical decisions within a rule. My attempt:

---

```
Set-AdfsAdditionalAuthenticationRule -AdditionalAuthenticationRules 'c1:[type ==
"http://schemas.microsoft.com/ws/2012/01/insidecorporatenetwork", value == "false"] && 
(NOT EXISTS([type == "http://schemas.microsoft.com/2012/01/requestcontext/claims/x-ms-client-ip",
Value =~ "^(?i)2003:6a:7d12:3f58:148:f23:cdc4:4181$"])) 
 => issue(type =
"http://schemas.microsoft.com/ws/2008/06/identity/claims/authenticationmethod", value =
"http://schemas.microsoft.com/claims/multipleauthn" );'
```

Produces an error at the "NOT EXISTS" no matter what I do. Any help greatly appreciated. The idea is to require all external IPs except the one in the list of IPs (regex) to use MFA.

**EDIT: I TRIED THE FOLLOWING**

the only thing that I still can't get working is the IP-address check. Is there a way I can debug to see what is happening (ip found or result of regex etc.)?

```
$RhtMfaClaimRule = 'NOT EXISTS([type == 
"http://schemas.microsoft.com/2012/01/requestcontext/claims/x-ms-client-ip", Value =~ "^(?i)81.151.139.145$"]) => add(type = "http://schemas.company.com/temp", value = "true" ); 
c1:[type == "http://schemas.company.com/temp"] && 
c2:[type == "http://schemas.microsoft.com/ws/2012/01/insidecorporatenetwork", value == "false"] => issue(type = "http://schemas.microsoft.com/ws/2008/06/identity/claims/authenticationmethod", value = "http://schemas.microsoft.com/claims/multipleauthn" );'

Set-AdfsAdditionalAuthenticationRule $RhtMfaClaimRule
```

**EDIT: Learned from logging**
The rules appear to be ok since a regexp of ".asterix" for the filtered IP turns off MFA from external as expected. But as soon as I change it to anything but .asterix, I get prompted for the MFA again. So, suspecting the client-ip claim, looking at the logs. I see the calling IP is visible in the request context header, so far so good, but in the thousands of trace entries, I do not see the client-ip claim yet. I suspect I have to tell Office365 to forward this somewhere in my ADFS-daschboard "Edit Claim rules for Microsoft Identity Platform". Any idea what I need to precisely add there for this client-ip claim to be forwarded?

**EDIT. Probably SOLVED**

The posts shown below helped. The ms-client-ip claim used above is apparently only for inhouse clients. Desperation led me to really look at the claim details, and replacing the x-ms-client claim with the following one from the request context apparently does the trick -- initial tests successful.

http://schemas.microsoft.com/2012/01/requestcontext/claims/x-ms-forwarded-client-ip

Comment: https://blogs.technet.microsoft.com/askds/2012/06/26/an-adfs-claims-rules-adventure/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't AND EXISTS rules AFAIK.

Try something like:

NOT EXISTS([type == "http://schemas.microsoft.com/2012/01/requestcontext/claims/x-ms-client-ip",
Value =~ "^(?i)2003:6a:7d12:3f58:148:f23:cdc4:4181$"])) 
 => add(type =
"http://schemas.company.com/temp", value = "true" );

and then:

c1:[type == "http://schemas.company.com/temp"] &&
c2:[type ==
"http://schemas.microsoft.com/ws/2012/01/insidecorporatenetwork", value == "false"]
=> issue(type =
"http://schemas.microsoft.com/ws/2008/06/identity/claims/authenticationmethod", value =
"http://schemas.microsoft.com/claims/multipleauthn" );'

Comment: Thanks. I noticed :-) Tried it but no success yet. Please see my edit.

Comment: Please see edits above for logging learned. I suspect I have to tell Office365 to forward this somewhere in my ADFS-daschboard "Edit Claim rules for Microsoft Identity Platform". Any idea what I need to precisely add there for this client-ip claim to be forwarded? Thanks!

Comment: See my edits above. The link from nzpmad above showed me which claim to use, so marking as answer. Use this http://schemas.microsoft.com/2012/01/requestcontext/claims/x-ms-forwarded-client-ip instead of x-ms-client-ip.